# Null checking in spring expression language

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am experiencing a strange behaviour when checking null pointer in a date field inside a collection object

```
public class FilterTest {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
              Collection<EmployeeDto> employees = new ArrayList<EmployeeDto>();
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("", 1111, new Date()));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("123", 2222, null));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("22", 3333, new Date()));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("22", 4444, null));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("11", 5555, null));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("22", 6666, null));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto(null, 6666,null));

           StandardEvaluationContext stdContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
           stdContext.setVariable("emps", employees);      

           ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();    


          **String key4= "#emps.?[dateOfBirth != null ? T(DateUtil).formatDate(dateOfBirth), 'dd/MM/yyyy').contains('25/07/2012') : false]" ;**          


              Collection<Object> proj1 = (Collection<Object>) parser.parseExpression(
                      key4).getValue(stdContext);
              System.out.println(proj1);    



}
class EmployeeDto {
       String name;
       public String getName() {
              return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
              this.name = name;
       }

       public int getAge() {
              return age;
       }

       public void setAge(int age) {
              this.age = age;
       }

       int age;
       Date dateOfBirth;

       public EmployeeDto(String name, int age, Date dateOfBirth) {
              this.name = name;
              this.age = age;
              this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
       }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

The expression should return collection of objects satisfying the condition. But now , I am getting an exception that dateOfBirth cannot be found on null. So I tried with a new expression

```
 String key4= "#emps.?[dateOfBirth != null ? T(DateUtil).formatDate(#emps.![dateOfBirth], 'dd/MM/yyyy').contains('25/07/2012') : false]" ;
```

This works fine. But when I add null in the first object of the collection, it return results as 0, and when I checked, I found that null is passed to the DateUtil class formatDate method. ie the emploee collection is like 
    `

```
employees.add(new EmployeeDto("", 1111, null)); // first value is null, and I am getting empty result, but there is one corrrect result
           **employees.add(new EmployeeDto("12", 2222, null));**
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("22", 3333, new Date()));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("33", 4444, null));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("FIVE", 5555, null));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto("SIX", 6666, null));
           employees.add(new EmployeeDto(null, 6666,null));
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue, can anyone tell the correct expression I should use?

Answer (score 0):

In your DateUtil class, add a method like:

```
    public static boolean isSameDay(Date date1, Date date2) {
        if (date1 == null || date2 == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(date1);
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.setTime(date2);
        return isSameDay(cal1, cal2);
    }
```

Then just do:

```
StandardEvaluationContext stdContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
stdContext.setVariable("emps", employees);
stdContext.setVariable("yourTestDate", new Date());
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();   

String key4 = "#emps.?[T(DateUtil).isSameDate(dateOfBirth, yourTestDate)]" ;
Collection<Object> proj1 = (Collection<Object>) parser.parseExpression(key4).getValue(stdContext);
System.out.println(proj1);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But in my case I need the formatted date collection avoiding nulls depending on the date format. it is not just a boolean value checking it is same date, How I can acheive this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried with your answer, but still I am getting the exception Field or property 'dateOfBirth' cannot be found on null

Comment: I tried different options, but when I give null in the first collection object, it is not working and returns empty result. But it works if the first object is not null

Comment: So, why do you need to use Spring Expression Language? Could you the Guava Collections? http://marxsoftware.blogspot.fr/2011/10/filtering-and-transforming-java.html

Answer (score 0):

You asked a similar question the other day - in this case, you need to perform the projection on the RESULTS of a collection selection. Here is a simpler example...

```
    Expression exp = new SpelExpressionParser()
        .parseExpression("(#emps.?[name != null]).![name.toUpperCase()]");
```

The first part (...) selects those elements that meet the criteria; it then performs projection on that new collection.

Comment: I tried this, but still I am getting exception. The key I given is,(#emps.?[dateOfBirth != null]).![T(DateUtil).filterDate(dateOfBirth, 'dd/MM/yyyy')], in this DateUtil. filterdate method format the date to the specified format. But I am getting an exception that Field or property 'dateOfBirth' cannot be found on null, you can see that in the employeedto, I had given the first value of dateofbirth as null . Could you please help me how I can correct thid, thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you work through it step-by-step. First evaluate the selection, to make sure you are getting what you expect. #emps.?[dateOfBirth != null] - does that give you a collection of objects with non-null DOB. You can do it with several expressions one after another. Once you have debugged it, you should be able to reassemble into a single expression.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, I debugged the code and understood that, the exception thrown when I tried to call the method. [T(DateUtil).filterDate(dateOfBirth, 'dd/MM/yyyy']. When I just give, #emps.?[dateOfBirth != null].![dateOfBirth], I am getting the values, the problem is with the function calling, do you have any idea on this, thanks for your support